# Color matching by color mapping using feature detection

Tags: ffmpeg

My goal is to match colors of two videos filming the same scene at slightly different positions. For this purpose, I created an algorithm that searches for corresponding features in one matching still frame of both videos. I then normalized the color relationships of the matching pixels

```
(r-value + 1) / 256
(g-value + 1) / 256
(b-value + 1) / 256
```

and converted them into curves as in

```
curves=r='0.1/0.2 ...':g=....'
```

Yet the result is rubbish.

I need to actually tell ffmpeg with a number of rgb-values: "This rgb-value is to be this rgb-value" and not separately map each red value of for instance 66 to 22, but map each 66-22-18 to 44-77-123. The missing mappings should be interpolated.

Or can a list of

```
Color1 maps to Color2
```

be converted into curves or similar?

Comment: What you need is to apply a LUT. See https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#haldclut-1

Comment: @Gyan What is better, a LUT or midequalizer?

Comment: Haven't tried the mideq filter yet. Give it a try, but based on its description, the result won't be a match for the reference.